# Frama-C behaviors and value analysis

Tags: frama-c

I want to use Frama-C to analyze a program containing
a `read`-like function: given a buffer `buf` and its length `len`, the function writes exactly `len` bytes in `buf` (unless there is an error).

I used ACSL to specify it, but the value analysis is giving
me weird results.

Here's my specification, plus a `main` function for testing:

```
/*@
  assigns \result \from \nothing;
  assigns *(buf+(0..len-1)) \from \nothing;
  behavior ok:
    requires \valid(buf+(0..len-1));
    ensures  \result == 0;
    ensures  \initialized(buf+(0..len-1));
  behavior error:
    ensures  \result == -1;
 */
int read(char *buf, int len);

int main() {
  char buf[10];
  read(buf, 10);
  return 0;
}
```

When running `frama-c -val test.c` (I'm using Frama-C Neon), I obtain this result:

```
[value] Analyzing a complete application starting at main
[value] Computing initial state
[value] Initial state computed
[value] Values of globals at initialization

[value] computing for function read <- main.
        Called from test.c:16.
[value] using specification for function read
test.c:6:[value] Function read, behavior ok: precondition got status valid.
test.c:10:[value] Function read, behavior error: this postcondition evaluates to false in this
        context. If it is valid, either a precondition was not verified for this
        call, or some assigns/from clauses are incomplete (or incorrect).
[value] Done for function read
[value] Recording results for main
[value] done for function main
[value] ====== VALUES COMPUTED ======
[value] Values at end of function main:
  NON TERMINATING FUNCTION
```

I did put `assigns`/`from` clauses, and there are no preconditions for the `error` behavior (so, by default, they are verified).

What is going on here? How can I make the analysis work in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the message, the actual issue is that there is an error in the specification of the `read` function: both behaviors are active at the *same time*, since they contain no `assumes` clauses (implicitly, both have `assumes \true`). Therefore, both `ensures` clauses are true, which implies `\result == 0 && \result == 1`.

This error leads to a contradictory state, where the result of the
function is both 0 and 1 (simultaneously), thus no result can be returned,
and therefore the function is considered as non-terminating.

One of the several possible solutions here consists in adding a
non-deterministic ghost variable, say `_read_state`, to represent the
internal state of the function, and then using this variable to define
disjoint `assumes` clauses for the different behaviors:

```
//@ ghost volatile int _read_state;
/*@
  assigns \result \from \nothing;
  assigns *(buf+(0..len-1)) \from \nothing;
  behavior ok:
    assumes _read_state == 0;
    requires \valid(buf+(0..len-1));
    ensures  \result == 0;
    ensures  \initialized(buf+(0..len-1));
  behavior error:
    assumes _read_state != 0;
    ensures  \result == -1;
 */
```

Notice the `== 0` and `!= 0` comparisons are arbitrary; any set of possibly disjoint values would work here.

Using this specification, we obtain the expected result for this program:

```
[value] Analyzing a complete application starting at main
[value] Computing initial state
[value] Initial state computed
[value] Values of globals at initialization
  _read_state ∈ [--..--]
[value] computing for function read <- main.
        Called from test.c:18.
[value] using specification for function read
tread.c:7:[value] Function read, behavior ok: 
    precondition got status valid. 
    (Behavior may be inactive, no reduction performed.)
[value] Done for function read
[value] Recording results for main
[value] done for function main
[value] ====== VALUES COMPUTED ======
[value] Values at end of function main:
  buf[0..9] ∈ [--..--] or UNINITIALIZED
  __retres ∈ {0}
```